# How to destructure a pandas dataframes.loc result?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flask

I'm attempting to destructure the results of a pandas dataframe.loc search into various variables. Then, I want to add those variables to an object and push the object to a results array. I need to repeat these steps for all matching rows.

However, I can't figure out how to destructure the results of a pandas dataframe.loc correctly.

Here's my code:

```
# First I search through the sorted_csv and find all the rows 
# where First Name is "Cary". This works, and returns all the matching rows.
foundResults = sorted_csv.loc[sorted_csv["First Name"] == "Cary"]
       
# Then I need to destructure each found row, create an object, 
# and push it to a results array
for row in foundResults:
    # Error here ** 
    idx, first_name, last_name, state, phonenumber = row

    # Create object
    row_to_search_match_dict = {
            "first_name": first_name,
            "last_name": last_name,
            "state": state,
            "phonenumber": phonenumber
    }

    # Push to results array
    results.append(row_to_search_match_dict)
```

** Error code: code errors at `idx, first_name, last_name`... and the error message is `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)`.

I've tried to remove `idx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be too many entries in your row for what you're trying to assign it to.

It has too many values into too little space. Try doing

```py
for row in foundResults[["idx", "first_name", "last_name", "state", "phonenumber"]]:
```

to specifically choose the number of elements in your row